# Passing query string through variable value fails

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2015

This works

```
create procedure Checking1(@SQLQueryString nvarchar(max))
as
begin

select * from MyTable

end
```

This is not working

```
create procedure Checking1(@SQLQueryString nvarchar(max))
as
begin

@SQLQueryString

end;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16  or https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: Please move your suggestion as answer.  I will mark it as answer. From your source I understand that I need to call it as like exec(@SQLQueryString).

Comment: What value is the stored procedure providing here?

Comment: QueryString Through Variable (i.e.) "select * from MyTable"

Comment: How is it any easier to execute the stored proc and pass the sql as a parameter vs just executing the sql string?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Passing a string to just execute is a ***HUGE*** security vulnerability. What controls do you have to stop a user running `DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable` or `CREATE LOGIN a WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER a;`?

Comment: I'd advise you not to use such a procedure as it forces you to always use SQL injection. If you need a dynamic query consider using `sp_executesql` which allows you to use parameters where possible.

Comment: Also there is no "Microsoft SQL Server 2015"

Comment: My Query is huge which goes to 150+ lines using joins on multiple tables as well as used pivot also.  I just want to pass the part of query string from .Net code using this Stored Procedure.

Comment: 150 lines isn't huge, in my opinion, @Sixthsense . And a 150+ line statement/batch doesn't make it "ok" to make a procedure that blindly executes what ever is passed to it...

Comment: I agree, I just creating using my limited knowledge :)

Comment: Then just *don't* do this, @Sixthsense . It's a security vulnerability just waiting to be exploited. What you have is basically giving someone **1 billion** characters to do *what ever* they want on your instance.

Comment: Just 1 question, how others can able to know my SQL Server connection string and password to do the things which you listed above.  (Drop/Create/Change Policy etc.,)?

Comment: `EXEC dbo.Checking1 N'DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;';` @Sixthsense . That's injection 101.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246851/discussion-between-sixthsense-and-larnu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell SQL Server to execute your dynamic-SQL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
or
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/